# C++Num in char array to int

Tags: c++, arrays, char, int

I have a large number stored into a char array and I return it into a cout.

```
#include <iostream>

int num()
{
    char num[] = "160919040944";

    return (int)num;
}
int main()
{
    std::cout << num();

    return 0;
}
```

It prints out a random number instead of the one I specified.

Comment: `(int)num` doesn't do what you think it does. It produces the numeric value of the memory address at which the first character of `num` happens to be stored. In any case, the number `160919040944` won't fit in an `int` on most platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, `(int)num` doesn't do it. What yo need is to return a `long long` from your function via [`std::stoll`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

```
long long num()
{
    char num[] = "160919040944";
    return std::stoll(num); // need conversion to long due to overflowing an int
}
```

The function [`std::stoll`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) converts a `std::string` (in this case implicitly constructed from the `char*`) to a `long long int`.

Thanks @Lorehead for the comment

Comment: Since `long` on many platforms is 32 bits, what you need is `long long`.

Comment: @Lorehead correct, works on my platform (`long` happens to be 8 bytes), but you're absolutely right, `long long` is guaranteed at least 64 bits, edited.